# MacOS & Android Studio - generated apks (file) cannot be installed on device

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk

I am using androidStudio (3.3) on MacOS (I just moved from windows to mac). 
The Apk (signed & unsigned can be generated), the unsigned packages can be installed and executed on the emulator environment.

But when I try to install it on a real device (copy on SD, allow installation from other sources), the installation fails:

Error message: app cannot be installed since package seems to be corrupt.

This issue occurs for

- unsigned apks
- signed apks

If I rename the extension from apk to zip (apk is acutally a zip file), I am able to open it without any issues. I never had the issue as long I was working with an Windows PC

At the final end I need a (signed) apk that can be uploaded to google play...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you install apk(package name) on your device you see this error when you want install new apk :

> app cannot be installed since package seems to be corrupt.

For fix that

**1)** You can uninstall app from device and reinstall from apk.

**2)** You can change **versionCode** in build.gradle(app)

```
  defaultConfig {
        applicationId your_package_name   
        versionCode 2 //try to increase every time
        versionName "1.0.0" //no need to change but better change it
        //other codes
  }
```

Remember that you can not share debug apk file from device and made this error too.

Comment: Many thanks... You are correct.. The reason was that the "versionCode" was lower than the original version code (and the error message was misleading).

Many thanks!